# How many different groups can be made?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a group with 2 elements. Cayley's theorem says that every group is isomorphic to the permutation group. So if a group had 2 elements would there be 2! different groups; for 3 elements, 3! groups and so on?

Comment: It's the very first entry in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A000001.

Comment: Also, for $n$ prime, there is only one group of order $n$, not $n!$. In particular, there is only one group of order $2$ and only one group of order $3$.

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: Every group of prime order is cyclic. This is a consequence of [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)).

Answer (score 1):

Cayley's Theorem gives us that every group is isomorphic to a **subgroup** of the permutation group.

For example, $S_2 \cong C_2$ is the *only* group of order $2$. Also, $C_3$ is the cyclic group of $3$ elements, which is a subgroup of $S_3$ (which has order $6$). This is the *only* group of order $3$. Thus the $n!$ claim on the distinct groups of order $n$ (up to isomorphism) is not correct.

This comes all from the definition of a group. Say that we have a group $G = \{e,a\}$ where $e$ is the identity and $a\neq e,~ a^2 = e$. What other group can be formed from this? You have to have an identity. You have to have an element that is not the identity. If $a^2 \neq e$, then $a^2 = a$, as that is the only other option. But then $a =e$ since we can multiply both sides of $a^2 = a$ by the inverse of $a$ (which must exist by the definition of a group). No matter what you do, you will only be able to create one group of order 2. Similar things happen for a group of order 3. The counter examples to the $n!$ claim (especially for small $n$) come from the bare rudiments of group theory, so with just a little background you should be able to tackle the concepts.

Comment: Ok so is my assertion wrong?

Comment: Yes. You have misstated Cayley's Theorem.

Comment: Ok but I am not seeing why a group of 3 elements could not form 6 different groups or that two elements could not for 2 different groups. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Much of the understanding in this regard will be based on how well you understand beginning group theory. I have updated my answer a bit more.